# load folder from S3 for ML in ECS - AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, machine-learning

I am deploying an ml model on AWS (docker container in ECS EC2).

The first step of the script is to load a whole folder from the S3 bucket (~43 GB), which contains all the file artifacts.

I passed KEY and ACCESS as an environmental variable on the task definition. I confirmed that those match my account. However, when I run a task, I get "boto3 access denied".

What am I missing? Should I do something different if loading a whole folder?

The code I am using to access the folder is:

```
my_file = 'folder_artifacts'
session = boto3.Session( aws_access_key_id=KEY, aws_secret_access_key= ACCESS)
s3client = boto3.client('s3')
response = s3client.get_object(Bucket=my_bucket, Key=my_file)
model_id = response['Body']
```

Comment: `session = boto3.Session( aws_access_key_id=KEY, aws_secret_access_key= ACCESS)` show where KEY and ACCESS are defined

Comment: Make sure you have sufficient priviledges to download files from S3. You must set proper IAM policy or S3 bucket policy to give the right to user/role to download files from S3.

Comment: I added '/' to the 'folder_artifacts'. The error changed to
"TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not StreamingBody"

I do have permissions. I added KEY and ACCESS as variable to ECS task definition.